# Calculate the empirical distribution of a sequence in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose `A` is a (NumPy) length-`M` array of integers in 0, 1, ..., `N-1`, I would like to calculate an array of length `N`, `c`, such that `c[i] = sum(A == i)`.  A `for`-based solution is obvious, but is there a faster solution?

I am also aware of [`np.histogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) but it sounds like a bit of overkill for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution.

```
N = 10 # just an example
M = 10000
A = np.random.randint(0, N, size=M)

# for-based solution
c1 = [sum(A == i) for i in range(N)]

# using numpy unique

c2 = np.zeros(N, dtype=int)
val, count = np.unique(A, return_counts=True)
c2[val] = count


assert all(c2 == c1)
```